# What is the differential of the logarithm on a matrix Lie group?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, logarithms, lie-groups

If $G \subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a matrix Lie group, then the manifold and matrix logarithm coincide at the identity.

I recall seeing a formula of a closed-form expression of the differential of the matrix logarithm (wrt $G$): $d \log_g:T_gG \to T_{\mathfrak{g}}\mathfrak{g}\cong \mathfrak{g}$. It involved an infinite series and the Bernoulli numbers. However, I am unable to find it anywhere. Could someone find this?

I will accept any answer writing this as an infinite series that references the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: I’m sorry, but this is for the exponential map, not the logarithm map as I asked. such information isn’t on that Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

You might choose to "invert"/rewrite [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement). That is, given the Lie algebra element $X(t)=\log G(t)$, and $\operatorname{ad}_x = \log \operatorname{Ad}_G$,
$$
 \frac{d\log G}{dt}= \frac{\operatorname{Ad}_G ~~\log \operatorname{Ad}_G}{\operatorname{Ad}_G-{\mathbb I}} ~~G^{-1} \frac{dG}{dt} .
$$

This is the standard seat-of-the-pants expression utilized in routine physics applications; I'm sure you may circumscribe/delimit it and refashion it to you liking.

WP has the evident connection to the [generating function  of the Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function) for powers of the group adjoint Ad operator,
$$
   \frac{\operatorname{Ad}_G  }{\operatorname{Ad}_G-{\mathbb I}}  = \sum^\infty_{m=0} B_m^- {(\operatorname{Ad}_G)^m\over m!}  ~~~.
$$